# Qt calling tryLock() multiple times on the same mutex from the same thread (5.13.2 ver.)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11, deadlock

I have a question about the method bool QMutex::tryLock(int timeout).
I notice that the description of this method in different (i.e. 5.15 and 6.4) versions are slightly different.

- In  5.15 ver., the document says "Calling this function multiple times on the same mutex from the same thread is allowed if this mutex is a recursive mutex. If this mutex is a non-recursive mutex, this function will always return false when attempting to lock the mutex recursively."
- In 6.4 ver., the document says "Calling this function multiple times on the same mutex from the same thread will cause a dead-lock."

I'm using Qt 5.13.2 version now. Is it alright to call tryLock multiple times on the same thread? Or the document of 5.15 ver. is incorrect. Thanks!

refs:

- Qt 5.15 ver.: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qmutex.html#tryLock
- Qt 6.4.1 ver.: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmutex.html#tryLock-1

I sent a mail to the QT Team, but haven't receive the feedback yet.

Comment: 5.13 version preceds 5.15 which in turn preceds 6.4. So the change from recursive mutexes to regular ones happened afterwards. So it is most likely you can, but you should test it to verify. Regardless, you should almost never use recursive mutex. The information that the mutex unlocks when you trigger unlock tends to be important in multithreading, without it you can easily trigger a deadlock an any conditional wait.

Comment: Okay, we will keep these in mind and have more detailed tests on our software

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's make sure we are on the same page as to exactly what the documentation is talking about, and exactly what you are trying to do:

The Qt documentation talks about "attempting to lock the mutex ***recursively***".

This means: obtaining a lock on the mutex, and while being in possession of that lock, proceeding to invoke some other function within your code which also attempts to obtain a lock on the same mutex.

Apparently, Qt 5.15 supported this kind of behavior by means of some special kind of mutex called a "recursive mutex", whereas a regular mutex would just fail the 2nd attempt to lock, despite the fact that your thread would already be in possession of a lock on that mutex.

And apparently, in Qt 6.4.1 they have done away with this mechanism, so they have fallen back to a more primitive behavior: attempting to re-acquire a lock on a mutex while already in possession of a lock on that mutex will deadlock. (Presumably, they have done away with recursive mutexes.)

The prudent thing to do is to design for the future and to refrain from using functionality that was only available in Qt 5.15 and is known to miserably fail starting with Qt 6.4.1. Your software will need to evolve, so you will inevitably encounter the need to upgrade to a later version of Qt.

Besides that, it is a good software design practice to always be in control of everything that you do, so you should always know whether you have obtained a lock on a certain mutex or not, so you should never be attempting to lock a mutex twice. Qt 6.4.1 appears to have been designed under the assumption that you are following this practice.

As to whether it will work, the answer is that we cannot really tell, given the documentation that you have cited; but if the 5.15 documentation (which you have cited) also applies to version 5.13.2 (which you are currently using) and if your mutex is a recursive mutex, then it should work.

Comment: Peeking at the docs, QT 5.14 added a `QRecursiveMutex` class, which is presumably what one should use if they explicitly want a recursive mutex (accepting the additional cost of constructing one) and a `QMutex` otherwise.

Comment: LOL, I didn't notice that QRecursiveMutex has been removed from QT in the 6.4 version. Thanks for reminding me!!!

Comment: As for the design issue, due to the hardware limitation, we are designing a 'two-level parallel system', which is there are multiple threads in the software, each thread controls multiple 'clients', and each client is independent. So unfortunately it seems like we must solve this problem. BTW, these comments are awesome.